# Is it possible for an already installed android application to add jar file and run the functions from jar

Tags: android

Is it possible for an already installed android application to automatically add a jar file and run the functions from the jar

Comment: You can't do this from java's jar but may call methods from dex file.... Read about DexClassLoader

Comment: Thanks.Can you provide an example or tutorial link.

Comment: Hi, Selvin. I have read about DexClassLoader. Now I can call a method from a dexclass. But, I can't pass a parameter to that from my main application. Can you help me? Here is my specific question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422487/android-reflection-giving-no-such-method-exception